# Vlookup and match excel function to VBA?

Tags: performance, excel, match, vlookup, vba

```
=VLOOKUP($I13,Data!$B$13:$XFD$1048576,MATCH(M$10,Data!$B$11:$XFD$11,0),FALSE)
```

This is the function I am trying to translate to `VBA` to increase efficiency.

The purpose is to link the date on page to another page (**I13**) and then match the heading from one page to another (**M10**) so that when I enter a new header it pulls the data automatically from a sheet full with data. That is what the above function did how do i convert to `VBA`?

Thank you

Comment: *how do i convert to VBA* - [what you have actually tried?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Check out  [Vlookup Userform](http://www.xlorate.com/excel-questions.html#Vlookup%20In%20UserForm)...shows how to use vlookup in vba

Comment: *hint:* You will have to know which worksheet `I13` and `M10` are on.

Comment: This is what you want if you are trying to increase efficiency: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this function but not succeed,

```
1   2   3   4           1   2   3   4
```

Yash    123 255 1000    2000        Yash    123 255 1000    2000
ABC 234 456 5000    8000        ABC 234 456 5000    8000
XYZ 567 998 12000   18000       XYZ 567 998 12000   18000
                        XYZ 567 998 12000   18000
                        Yash    123 255 1000    2000
                        ABC 234 456 5000    8000
                        Yash    123 255 1000    2000
                        XYZ 567 998 12000   18000
                        XYZ 567 998 12000   18000

```
Sub yash()
r = 2
Do While Cells(r, 7) <> ""
Cells(r, 8) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(r, 7), Range("A2:E4"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, 8), Range("A1:E1"), 0), 0)
Cells(r, 9) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(r, 7), Range("A2:E4"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, 9), Range("A1:E1"), 0), 0)
Cells(r, 10) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(r, 7), Range("A2:E4"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, 10), Range("A1:E1"), 0), 0)
Cells(r, 11) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(r, 7), Range("A2:E4"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, 11), Range("A1:E1"), 0), 0)
r = r + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

to demonstrate it please copy all and paste in cell("A1") from line 2 in this comment.

Comment: 123456789102345678

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. With respect, your answer needs more explanation so the questioner can tell what you need. Also, you can [edit] an answer rather than posting a second answer with similar content.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeEjz.jpg)

```
Sub yash()
r = 2
Do While Cells(r, 7) <> ""
Cells(r, 8) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(r, 7), Range("A2:E4"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, 8), Range("A1:E1"), 0), 0)
Cells(r, 9) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(r, 7), Range("A2:E4"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, 9), Range("A1:E1"), 0), 0)
Cells(r, 10) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(r, 7), Range("A2:E4"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, 10), Range("A1:E1"), 0), 0)
Cells(r, 11) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(r, 7), Range("A2:E4"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, 11), Range("A1:E1"), 0), 0)
r = r + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

to demonstrate it please copy all and paste in cell("A1") from line 2 in this comment.